# Refreshing Angular Emojis when using property binding

Tags: angular, typescript, emoji, property-binding

I'm new to programming, so sorry if the question is stupid.
I'm using [Angular Emojis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-emojis), i show specific emojis with a variable using property binding.

Template:

```
<angular-emojis [name]="emojivar" size="30" (mouseenter)="changeRoutine()" > </angular-emojis>
```

TypeScript code:

```
  emojivar = 'taco';

  changeRoutine(){
    console.log(this.emojivar);
    this.emojivar = 'tomato';
    console.log(this.emojivar);
  }
```

The variable changes, but the emoji doesn't change.
Is there any way to fix it, to make it refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly i don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. You could try to force change detection:

```
consturctor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

changeRoutine(){
    console.log(this.emojivar);
    this.emojivar = 'tomato';
    console.log(this.emojivar);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

[EDIT]
I had a look at the library you are using and...it doesn't handle changes at all:

https://github.com/saqy/angular-packages/blob/master/projects/angular-emojis/src/lib/angular-emojis.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply, but unfortunately that doesn't work.
I even tried this.ngOnInit, that did'nt work as well.

Comment: you seem to be one of the first to use this...library. i created a pull request to add change detection to it...but i'd advise you to look for an alternative, more sophisticated library...

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look for another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and it worked for me.

**TS**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  name = 'Angular';
  emojiName = '';
  emojiSize = 20;
  index = -1;

  list = [
    'full_moon_with_face',
    'first_quarter_moon_with_face',
    'star',
    'star2',
    'sun_with_face',
  ];

  function(str, i) {
    this.index = -1;
    this.emojiName = str;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.index = i;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<p>Click on any emoji to see the Result</p>

<span *ngFor="let emoji of list; index as i">
  <angular-emojis
    [name]="emoji"
    size="20"
    (click)="function(emoji, i)"
  ></angular-emojis>
</span>

<hr />
Resultant Emoji:
<angular-emojis
  *ngIf="index != -1"
  [name]="emojiName"
  [size]="emojiSize"
></angular-emojis>
```

You can [run and check](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfk6zt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the results here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31478793)